# We write all the positive integers run together as follows: $123456789101112131415 . . .$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

We write all the positive integers run together as follows:
$123456789101112131415 . . .$
What three digit number begins at the $2014th$ digit?

I was thinking number theory here. Modulus.

Can someone give me **hints, not answers**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As First $9$ numbers have single digit each and the next $99−9=90$ numbers have two digits each

$$1\cdot9+(99-9)\cdot2=189$$

Let the $x$ be the three digit number which makes $2013$ digits

$$\implies(x-99)\cdot3+189=2014-1$$

Clearly, $x+1$ will be the required three digit number

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do here. Why did you start with $1\cdot 0 + (99 - 9)\cdot 2$?

Comment: @JorleArbake, First $9$ numbers have single digit each, the next $99-9=90$ numbers have two digits each

Comment: This is a good answer, butI just need more explanation =) How is it $x+1$?

Comment: @JorleArbake, Please find the edited version

Comment: Okay. I understand more but there is still some doubt. What does $189$ mean there? Why do you have 189?

Comment: @JorleArbake, $189$ digits have been consumed by single and twi digit numbers

Comment: Wai, do you mean $189$ numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20523/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-jorlearbake).

Comment: Icannotjoin chat, not enough reputation

Comment: @JorleArbake, No, numbers between $1$ & $99$ inclusive

Comment: Okay, $90$ numbers have 2 digits right? why did you do $90*2$?

Comment: Isee because of how many digits. But why $(x -99$?

Comment: @JorleArbake, As the first $99$ natural numbers have at most two digits

Comment: Then how does $(x - 99)$ have three digits?

Comment: @JorleArbake, If the required number is $x,$ we have $x-100+1$ of them having three digits each

Comment: I see. Of numbers to $1000$ you aretaking away 99. Why not 100 becauseof $1000$ which is 4 digits?

Comment: $(x - 99)$ is how many numbers have 3digits correct? Then $x$ cannot be the required number/

Comment: It ishow you let $x = 99$in the above line to that. I dont understand this method at all.

Comment: OH! So you let $x$ by the $n-1$th digit?

Comment: How about $x - 98$ then we dont need $x+1$ do we? Just $x$?

Answer (score 4):

Well you've got 9 one digit numbers, then 90 two digit numbers and so on.  You don't need to use modular arithmetic.  Can you take it from here?